# Builder c++ Rave Reports encoding problem with cyrillic

Tags: c++, character-encoding, internationalization, rave-reports, cp1251

When  i  try save rave project in pdf\html file, have incorrect encoding. 
When choose format  and press SAVE, it ussually  save in iso-8859-1 code.
But i need cp1251 (cyrillic).

For example "Ïëîùàäü" instead of "Площадь".

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the best solution to your problem would be to use Unicode, rather than a codepage such as CP1251. Is it possible to use Unicode with Rave Reports?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I want o save reprt to pdf format. I have to create TRvRenderPDF and set it as RenderObject but pdf file was viewed not correctrly.

1. The TRvRenderPDF component not unicode-compatible(that is very bad) that is why all text in report coverted into Ansi with active codepage(for cyrillic it is CP1251). Now we have pdf file with text in CP1251 encoding.
2. As default TRvRenderPDF generate pdf with font TYPE1 Helvetica(by the standart of the format pdf it is build-in). But text is interpreted with encoding ISO 8859-1(or CP1252) but it encoding was CP1251 tha is why we have "Ïëîùàäü" or something analogous.

---

What we can to do:

1. Get font TYPE1(CP1252) where service symbols(numbers like in cyrillic letters in CP1251) replaced with cyrillic glyphs. For example [a link](http://binkd.spb.ru/omskland/Files/Paragraf/AGHelvetica.rar) and we need to install it.
2. Now we need tor replace old font name(Helvetica) from generated pdf document with new font name(AGHelvetica). You can dow it with text editor or i your's programm(read file -> find -> replace -> save file).

That all situation.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

P.P.S. If set property of pdf render EmbedBaseFonts = true, pdf document were saved with TrueType fonts, but problem stay. Neew to see to unicode render? but not this one.